# Flask broken pipe when redirecting after AJAX call

Tags: ajax, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an JQuery AJAX call:

```
$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_click_btn?btnId='+$(this).attr("id"),
          $('form').serialize(),
          function(data) {
             // return to send_messages page
             window.location = 'send_messages';
});
```

It doesn't do anything fancy. It just saves some form data to a database (using SQLAlchemy).  I put a break point on the window.location statement and the broken pipe won't happen if I delay the redirection by 1-2 seconds.  What's the best practice for handling this?

One other item of note is the DB session remains open after the AJAX call is complete.

The error message is below.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 813, in __bootstrap_inner self.run()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 766, in run self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/gui/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 656, in inner srv.serve_forever()
File "/gui/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 496, in serve_forever HTTPServer.serve_forever(self)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 238, in serve_forever
self._handle_request_noblock()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 297, in _handle_request_noblock
self.handle_error(request, client_address)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
self.process_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655, in __init__
self.handle()
File "/gui/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 216, in handle rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
self.handle_one_request()
File "/gui/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 251, in handle_one_request
return self.run_wsgi()
File "/gui/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in run_wsgi
execute(self.server.app)
File "/gui/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 184, in execute
write(data)
File "/gui/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 152, in write
self.send_header(key, value)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 401, in send_header
self.wfile.write("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: Could you please paste the rest of the error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary solution, I've added a 500 ms delay before redirecting.  Seems like there must be a better way, but this works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error too in an Ubuntu Docker container on Kubernetes on Ubuntu VM:

```
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 261, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 227, in write
    self.send_header(key, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 412, in send_header
    self.wfile.write("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I created a brand new Ubuntu xenial VM and ran the same code in Ubuntu Docker container on Kubernetes, and this error was **not** seen and Python Flask worked as expected. I think it was issue with my host (Ubuntu VM).